# How to extract a leading number from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a couple of string and I want to split them based on the numbers in it.

Ex:

1. 5Hello
2. 10HelloWorld
3. 16HelloWorldPython

In all these cases I want to extract the numbers that is 5, 10 and 16. The numbers could be up to infinity.

This is because I want to extract numbers and compare the length of the string whether they are equal or not.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\d+', inp)`

Comment: so you need to extract leading Digits from a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '5Hello')
[5]  
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '10HelloWorld')
[10]
```

Edit : Answer to the specific question

```
import re

def check_len(x):
  match = re.search(r'(\d+)(\w+)', x)
  return int(match[1])==len(match[2])

check_len('5hello')
True 

check_len('4rabbits')
False
```

Comment: What is 'r' in the findall function.

Comment: r indicates inside the single quotes it's a regular expression pattern

Comment: I came to know that we don't have to use 'r' in the function.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this

```
import re
def get_num(raw_str):
    number = re.search(r'\d+',raw_str)
    return number.group(0)
    
print(get_num('5hello'))    
print(get_num('10HelloWorld')) 
print(get_num('16HelloWorldPython'))
```